# Domain of validity of an inequality involving exponential and logarithms

Tags: inequality, logarithms, exponential-function

$$x^{{2(\log(x)})^3-1.5\log(x)} \geq 10^{1/2}$$

where $\log$ is decimal logarithm.

Just solve it and that's it. Can someone help me with some ideas or even with a solution? I have no idea how to deal with it.

So, I added logs to both sides and got.

$2t^4 -3/2t^2-1/2≥0 $
Where t = $\log(x)$

Then, $t^2$=z.

$4z^2-3z-1≥0$(i multiplied everything by 2)

D=25

z1=1,z2=-1/4.

What to do next?

Comment: What is $log_x$? You mean $logx$? Is so then for $x=1$ the inequality is simply wrong.

Comment: Sorry, edited. I mean log with a base - 10 and power - x

Comment: @Mark It is not a universal inequality. The question is : for which $x$ is it true ?

Comment: Oh, I see. Ok then.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Apply $\log$ to both sides and it becomes a quartic inequality of $\log x$.

Comment: You are right. The next step is to set $log_{10}(x)=X$.